# how to assign value to variables between if and elif statement?

Tags: python, if-statement

how to assign value to variables between if and elif statement?

It shows me "An illegal target for a variable annotation" when I assgin b = 2 between if and elif. I do not want to assign b = 2 before if statement.

```
a = 1

if a > 1:
   print("something")

b = 2
elif b > 1:
   print("something")
```

Comment: Why does it matter if you assign `b = 2` before or after `if a > 1`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 For speed, if the "if a > 1" get True, it will be excuted and it will not go to the elif condition. So why should I assign "b = 2" before "if a > 1" if the  "if a > 1" get True? Assign "b = 2" before "if a > 1" will be redundant step and take times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Python's assignment expressions. They let you assign a variable within a conditional, then return the value assigned. Like this:

```
a = 1

if a > 1:
   print("something")
elif (b := 2) > 1:
   print("something")
```

If you wanted to only assign the variable `b`, but not use it within the conditional, then you could rewrite your code as this (it is fairly ugly, but works in all cases):

```
a = 1

if a > 1:
   print("something")
elif (b := 2, EXPRESSION TO TEST)[1]:
   print("something")
```

Comment: But what is the point of that assignment + comparison? Shouldn't it just be an else.

Comment: This works for this particular example, but is not an answer to the problem as phrased in general.

Comment: @duckboycool I believe this would work for all problems of the type asked in the question. OP wants to assign a variable then use a statement in a conditional. If one only wanted to check if a > 0, it could be rewritten as `(b := 2) and a > 0`, because assignment expressions return the value they got assigned (which can be coerced to true if it is not 0).

Comment: @user2357112 Sorry, I updated my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

You simply don't write `elif` in such case.
Instead you write `else`, do what you want and `if`:

```
a = 1

if a > 1:
   print("something")
else:
   b = 2
   if b > 1:
      print("something")
```